# Scroll table when highlighted row is the last row visible in table body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have a table with 20 rows. By default first row is highlighted and 6 rows are visible in the screen. Now by navigating with down arrow highlighted row goes till 6th row and is visible in the screen but when it goes to 7th row it is now visible on the screen. So I want that when highlight reaches to 6th row the next row of table should be visible on the screen.

This snippet will help you to understand my question better.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var rowCount = $('#partyitem_table >tbody >tr').length;


    var $tbody = $("#partyitem_table tbody").on('click', 'tr', function() {
            highlight($(this));
    });

    function highlight($row) {
        if ($row.length) {
            $tbody.children().removeClass("highlight");
            $row.addClass('highlight');
        }
    }

    var firstrow = $tbody.find('tr').first();
    highlight(firstrow);



    /* Keydown event function to navigate the table row */
    $(document).keydown(function(e){

            switch(e.which){

                /* Up arrow */
                case 38:
                    var $prev = $tbody.find('.highlight').prev();
                    highlight($prev);

                    break;


                /* Down Arrow */
                case 40:
                    var $next = $tbody.find('.highlight').next();
                    highlight($next);

                    break;
            }
            /* End of Switch Case */
    });



});
```

```css
.fixed_header{
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 255px;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
}

.fixed_header thead {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.highlight{
    background-color: #3c8dbc;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="partyitem_table" class="table table-bordered fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>By</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>SrNo</th>
      <th>BrandSrNo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_body">
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>By</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>SrNo</td>
      <td>BrandSrNo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got the answer. scrollIntoView() is the function used to scroll in the visible area of the given element. Here below is the code.

> On Keydown Event

```
/* Keydown event function to navigate the table row */
    $(document).keydown(function(e){

            switch(e.which){

                /* Up arrow */
                case 38:

                    var $prev = $tbody.find('.highlight').prev();
                    highlight($prev);


                    var table_row = document.getElementById('partyitem_table').rows;
                    var selected_row = $('.highlight').index();
                    table_row[selected_row+=1].scrollIntoView(false);

                    break;


                /* Down Arrow */
                case 40:

                    var $next = $tbody.find('.highlight').next();
                    highlight($next);


                    var table_row = document.getElementById('partyitem_table').rows;
                    var selected_row = $('.highlight').index();
                    table_row[selected_row+=1].scrollIntoView(false);

                    break;
            }
            /* End of Switch Case */
    });
```